# JQUERY Autocomplete Not Showing Results That Are Returned From a php Script

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to fetch some school names using autocomplete.But the name list is not appearing. When I type something for example-"**uni**" it is making a request to sclist.php file like this ***sclist.php?term=uni***  and it returns this in response in the network console :

```
uni
 [
     "University of Cambridge",
     "University of Michigan",
     "University of Oxford",
     "University of Virginia" 
]
```

I can't seem to find why the list of names is not appearing. This is my first autocomplete implementation. Any help is much appreciated.

the **autocom.php** file:

```
<html lang = "en">
   <head>
      <meta charset = "utf-8">
      <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete functionality</title>
       <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
       <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

      <!-- Javascript -->
      <script>
         $(function() {
            $( "#automplete" ).autocomplete({
               source: 'sclist.php',
               autoFocus:true
               });
         });
      </script>
   </head>

   <body>
      <!-- HTML -->
       <p>Type something</p>
         <input id = "automplete">
  </body>
</html>
```

the **sclist.php** file:

```
<?php
require_once('connectToDB.php');
if (isset($_GET['term'])) 
    echo $_GET['term']."\n";
else 
  echo "not set";

require_once 'connectToDB.php';
$stmt=$portbleDocObj->prepare('SELECT name FROM Institution WHERE name LIKE :prefix ');
$stmt->execute(array( ':prefix'=>$_GET['term']."%") );

$returedData=array();
while ( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    $returedData[] = $row['name'];
}
print_r($row);
echo(json_encode($returedData, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
?>
```

Comment: `if (isset($_GET['term'])) { echo $_REQUEST['term']."\n";` ??? Why not `echo $_GET['term']` you just made sure that was there and set

Comment: you're not returning the valid json, because of that "uni"

Comment: @RiggsFolly not really... `PHP` syntax is fine.

Comment: @RiggsFolly And `print_r` doesn't mess the syntax. The `echo $_REQUEST['term']."\n";` does. `$row` is empty (null) at the end.

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes, but at the end it will only return null if it's not set or database will return no record. Your comment `You are missing a { after the } else` is a  bit missleading if you meant that all the rest of the code should be in it. And the better solution would be to use "return" or "die". The main problem why doesn't it work is that it's not a valid json because of `echo $_GET['term']."\n";` line. `null` or `false` will work fine, without an error when parsing the json by jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Basically I have just done a bit of a tidy up on your original code.
Remember, everything you echo or print when you are returning to an AJAX call will go back to the AJAX code to process. So only return what should be returned. Also when talking machine to machine the PRETTY_PRINT is unnecessary

```
<?php

if ( ! isset($_GET['term'])) {
    echo "not set";
} else {
    require_once('connectToDB.php');
    $stmt = $portbleDocObj->prepare('SELECT name 
                                    FROM Institution 
                                    WHERE name LIKE :prefix');

    $stmt->execute( [':prefix' => $_GET['term']."%"] );
    $ret = [];
    while ( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
        $ret[] = $row['name'];
    }   
    echo json_encode($returedData);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I find this approach more logical. works!!